# AWS Elastic beanstalk instance tags via spring boot framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have a Spring Boot micro service I've deployed on AWS EB now I want to pass in some data that could change via AWS instance tags. So I installed the `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws` package, then I updated my @Value annotations to

```
@Value("#{tag}")
```

Now after reading the documentation I was meant to load a bean which I tried by adding the XML to my resource folder

```
<beans ...>
    <aws-context:context-instance-data user-tags-map="instanceData" />
</beans
```

then used the `@Value("#{instanceData.tag}")` but that did not work.

So I removed the XML file above and I have the `@EnableContextInstanceData` annotation on my application class.

I have other apps in Cloud formation and I can read the tags but that's an older Spring project that is using XML bean files, etc. This project is using a Java based config and starter packages and is running on EB which is a requirement from the customer I work with.

Comment: so I think what I need to do is used Java based config to map the `user-tags-map` to instanceData or some other word but I not sure how to do that in Java the only info I can find has bean I need to load in a xml file.